# Residues theorem, and integrate

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus, complex-integration

> Evaluate $\int_\gamma\frac{z}{z^2+2z+5}dz$ where $\gamma$ is the unit
>   circle

I did but I don't know if it's right
$$z^2+2z+5=0\Leftrightarrow z=-1\pm 2i$$

this I have that $z_1=-1+2i$ and $z_2=-1-2i$ are the singularity points, then 
$$\int_\gamma \frac{z}{z^2+2z+5}dz=2\pi i*\sum_{i=1}^n [Res(f;z_i)]I(\gamma;z_i)$$
where $I(\gamma;z_i)=1$ if $z_i$ it is inside of $\gamma$ and $I(\gamma;z_i)=0$ if $z_i$ it is outside of $\gamma$. In that case $z_1$ and $z_2$ are outside of $\gamma$, so $$\int_\gamma \frac{z}{z^2+2z+5}dz=2\pi i*[0+0]=0$$

My reasoning is correct?

> EDIT: Evaluate $\int_\gamma \tan z \space dz$ where $\gamma$ is the
>   circle of radius $8$ centered at $0$

Someone could help me with this, I'm not thinking through solve it without using series.

Comment: Yes...you are correct.......

Comment: You are correct that this integral is zero.  But it is not correct that $I=1$ if the singularity is inside the closed contour.  The residue of a simple pole at $z_0$ is $\lim_{z\to z_0}(z-z_0)f(z)$.

Comment: @Dr.MV I do not know so I just applied the residue theorem that this statement in my book that way.

Comment: @Dr.MV you can help me with the second integrate?

Comment: Sure.  Note that $\cos z=0$ when $e^{i2z}=-1$ or when $(2n+1)\pi/2$.  Which of these zeroes lie in the circle $|z|=8$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT 1**:

The poles of $\tan z$ inside the circle $|z|=8$ are located at $\pm \pi/2$, $\pm 3\pi/2$, and $\pm 5\pi/2$.  The poles are of order $1$ and the residue at $(2n+1)\pi/2$ is

$$\lim_{z\to (2n+1)\pi/2}(z-(2n+1)\pi/2)\tan z$$

**HINT 2**:

To find the limit $\lim_{z\to (2n+1)\pi/2}(z-(2n+1)\pi/2)\tan z$ we use L'Hospital"s Rule.  To that end

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{z\to (2n+1)\pi/2}(z-(2n+1)\pi/2)\tan z&=\lim_{z\to (2n+1)\pi/2}\frac{(z-(2n+1)\pi/2)\sin z}{\cos z}\\\\
&=\lim_{z\to (2n+1)\pi/2}\frac{\sin z+(z-(2n+1)\pi/2)\cos z}{-\sin z}\\\\
&=-1
\end{align}$$

Comment: It is exactly there that's my doubts, beucase $lim_{z\rightarrow (2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}}tan z$ don't exists, then the product of the limit does not exist or not?

Comment: @askazy You are correct.  But $\lim_{z\to (2n+1)\pi/2}(z-(2n+1)\pi/2)\tan z=-1$, does it not.  Thus, the final answer is simply $-12\pi i$.

Comment: I really can not understand this limit

Comment: @askazy We may use L'Hospital's Rule to see that $\lim_{z\to (2n+1)\pi/2}(z-(2n+1)\pi/2)\tan z=-1$.